# How to get a list of all the methods of a class and its parameters

Tags: python

I have a requirement where i need to generate a list of all the methods and its parameters belonging to the Python class passed as argument.
I want something like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,attr1):
        pass
    def method1(self,param1,param2):
        pass
    def method2(self,param3):
        pass
    def method3(self):
        pass

def get_all_methods_details(className):
    # gets all the methods associated to the class along with its method.
```

When I do:

```
get_all_methods_details(myClass)
```

it should return something like this:

```
[(method1, param1,param2),(method2,param3),(method3)]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def get_all_method_details(className):
    return [ m for m in dir(className) if not m.startswith('__')]

print(get_all_method_details(MyClass))
```

this prints:

```
[method1, method2, method3]
```

I saw solutions for getting parameters from normal function but those does not work with methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.co_varnames`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute of the `code` object:

```py
def get_all_methods_details(class_name):
    return [
        (m, getattr(class_name, m).__code__.co_varnames)
        for m in dir(class_name)
        if not m.startswith("__")
    ]
```

This should return:

```
[('method1', ('self', 'param1', 'param2')), ('method2', ('self', 'param3')), ('method3', ('self',))]
```

As a side note, those are not [class methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). They are instance methods.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you :

```js
import inspect

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        pass

    def method1(self, param1, param2):
        pass

    def method2(self, param3):
        pass

    def method3(self):
        pass

def get_methods_and_params(cls):
    methods_and_params = []
    for name, member in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if inspect.ismethod(member) or inspect.isfunction(member):
            parameters = inspect.signature(member).parameters
            param_names = [param for param in parameters.keys() if param != 'self']
            methods_and_params.append((name, tuple(param_names)))
    return methods_and_params

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_class_methods = get_methods_and_params(MyClass)
    print(my_class_methods)
```

Let's understand the code :

1. We import the inspect module, which provides useful functions to inspect and introspect Python objects, such as classes, functions, and methods.
2. **for name, member in inspect.getmembers(cls)** This line uses the inspect.getmembers function to iterate over all members (attributes) of the class cls. It returns a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the name of the member and its corresponding value (attribute).
3. **if inspect.ismethod(member) or inspect.isfunction(member):** This line checks if the current member is either a method or a regular function. inspect.ismethod() and inspect.isfunction() are functions from the inspect module used to determine the type of an object.
4. **parameters = inspect.signature(member).parameters** If the member is a method or a function, this line retrieves the parameters of the function using inspect.signature. It returns an inspect.Signature object, which represents the signature of the method or function. The .parameters attribute of the inspect.Signature object provides a dictionary-like view of the function's parameters.
5. **param_names = [param for param in parameters.keys() if param != 'self']** This line creates a list called param_names that contains the names of the function's parameters, excluding the first parameter named 'self'. In Python, the first parameter of a method refers to the instance itself, and it is conventionally named 'self'.
6. **methods_and_params.append((name, tuple(param_names)))** This line adds a tuple to the methods_and_params list, containing the method's name (name) and a tuple of its parameter names (param_names).